# JSON java.sql.SQLException: Positioned Update not supported

Tags: ajax, json, hibernate, spring-mvc, java-web-start

I'm trying to use JSON in Java Web. Transform List to JSONArray by invoking JSONArray.fromObject(), but thrown the exception as following:

```
java.sql.SQLException: Positioned Update not supported.
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:1075)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:989)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:984)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:929)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ResultSetImpl.getCursorName(ResultSetImpl.java:2130)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.apache.commons.beanutils.PropertyUtilsBean.invokeMethod(PropertyUtilsBean.java:2170)
    at org.apache.commons.beanutils.PropertyUtilsBean.getSimpleProperty(PropertyUtilsBean.java:1332)
    at org.apache.commons.beanutils.PropertyUtilsBean.getNestedProperty(PropertyUtilsBean.java:770)
    at org.apache.commons.beanutils.PropertyUtilsBean.getProperty(PropertyUtilsBean.java:846)
    at org.apache.commons.beanutils.PropertyUtils.getProperty(PropertyUtils.java:426)
    at net.sf.json.JSONObject._fromBean(JSONObject.java:918)
    at net.sf.json.JSONObject.fromObject(JSONObject.java:168)
    at net.sf.json.AbstractJSON._processValue(AbstractJSON.java:265)
    at net.sf.json.JSONObject._processValue(JSONObject.java:2808)
    at net.sf.json.JSONObject.processValue(JSONObject.java:2874)
    at net.sf.json.JSONObject.setInternal(JSONObject.java:2889)
    at net.sf.json.JSONObject.setValue(JSONObject.java:1577)
    at net.sf.json.JSONObject._fromBean(JSONObject.java:934)
    at net.sf.json.JSONObject.fromObject(JSONObject.java:168)
    at net.sf.json.AbstractJSON._processValue(AbstractJSON.java:265)
    at net.sf.json.JSONObject._processValue(JSONObject.java:2808)
    at net.sf.json.JSONObject.processValue(JSONObject.java:2874)
    at net.sf.json.JSONObject.setInternal(JSONObject.java:2889)
    at net.sf.json.JSONObject.setValue(JSONObject.java:1577)
    at net.sf.json.JSONObject._fromBean(JSONObject.java:934)
    at net.sf.json.JSONObject.fromObject(JSONObject.java:168)
    at net.sf.json.AbstractJSON._processValue(AbstractJSON.java:265)
    at net.sf.json.JSONObject._processValue(JSONObject.java:2808)
    at net.sf.json.JSONObject.processValue(JSONObject.java:2874)
    at net.sf.json.JSONObject.setInternal(JSONObject.java:2889)
    at net.sf.json.JSONObject.setValue(JSONObject.java:1577)
    at net.sf.json.JSONObject._fromBean(JSONObject.java:934)
    at net.sf.json.JSONObject.fromObject(JSONObject.java:168)
    at net.sf.json.AbstractJSON._processValue(AbstractJSON.java:265)
    at net.sf.json.JSONObject._processValue(JSONObject.java:2808)
    at net.sf.json.JSONObject.processValue(JSONObject.java:2874)
    at net.sf.json.JSONObject.setInternal(JSONObject.java:2889)
    at net.sf.json.JSONObject.setValue(JSONObject.java:1577)
    at net.sf.json.JSONObject._fromBean(JSONObject.java:934)
    at net.sf.json.JSONObject.fromObject(JSONObject.java:168)
    at net.sf.json.AbstractJSON._processValue(AbstractJSON.java:265)
    at net.sf.json.JSONObject._processValue(JSONObject.java:2808)
    at net.sf.json.JSONObject.processValue(JSONObject.java:2874)
    at net.sf.json.JSONObject.setInternal(JSONObject.java:2889)
    at net.sf.json.JSONObject.setValue(JSONObject.java:1577)
    at net.sf.json.JSONObject._fromBean(JSONObject.java:934)
    at net.sf.json.JSONObject.fromObject(JSONObject.java:168)
    at net.sf.json.AbstractJSON._processValue(AbstractJSON.java:265)
    at net.sf.json.JSONObject._processValue(JSONObject.java:2808)
    at net.sf.json.JSONObject.processValue(JSONObject.java:2874)
    at net.sf.json.JSONObject.setInternal(JSONObject.java:2889)
    at net.sf.json.JSONObject.setValue(JSONObject.java:1577)
    at net.sf.json.JSONObject._fromBean(JSONObject.java:934)
    at net.sf.json.JSONObject.fromObject(JSONObject.java:168)
    at net.sf.json.AbstractJSON._processValue(AbstractJSON.java:265)
    at net.sf.json.JSONObject._processValue(JSONObject.java:2808)
    at net.sf.json.JSONObject.processValue(JSONObject.java:2874)
    at net.sf.json.JSONObject.setInternal(JSONObject.java:2889)
    at net.sf.json.JSONObject.setValue(JSONObject.java:1577)
    at net.sf.json.JSONObject._fromBean(JSONObject.java:934)
    at net.sf.json.JSONObject.fromObject(JSONObject.java:168)
    at net.sf.json.AbstractJSON._processValue(AbstractJSON.java:265)
    at net.sf.json.JSONObject._processValue(JSONObject.java:2808)
    at net.sf.json.JSONObject.processValue(JSONObject.java:2874)
    at net.sf.json.JSONObject.setInternal(JSONObject.java:2889)
    at net.sf.json.JSONObject.setValue(JSONObject.java:1577)
    at net.sf.json.JSONObject._fromBean(JSONObject.java:934)
    at net.sf.json.JSONObject.fromObject(JSONObject.java:168)
    at net.sf.json.AbstractJSON._processValue(AbstractJSON.java:265)
    at net.sf.json.JSONArray._processValue(JSONArray.java:2514)
    at net.sf.json.JSONArray.processValue(JSONArray.java:2539)
    at net.sf.json.JSONArray.addValue(JSONArray.java:2526)
    at net.sf.json.JSONArray._fromCollection(JSONArray.java:1057)
    at net.sf.json.JSONArray.fromObject(JSONArray.java:123)
    at org.vclub.model.json.Page2Json.getJsonFromList(Page2Json.java:11)
    at org.vclub.controller.TopicController.loadMoreTopic(TopicController.java:91)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:185)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:126)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:100)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:502)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:465)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:80)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:863)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:792)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:851)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:767)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:637)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:88)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:76)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:298)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:857)
    at org.apache
.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:588)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:489)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)
```

Actually,  according to online said, there are two solutions, modify the struts.xml or delete the getter method of DAO fields. I didn't use struts, so I have chose to delete the getter method of DAO fields in service. But it's still not working. I'm looking for help here. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

It seems like a **Hibernate lazy loading** problem.

If the object you want to format is some kind of hibernate model classes, and configure those classes to lazy load, this problem will happen.

**The reason** is that hibernate use cglib to dynamic generate this model classes(using subclass way to generate class), those sub-classes contain new attributes like "hibernateLazyInitializer". Then JSONObject will also try to serialize these new attributes. Then the exception happens.

You can try to add the following code to fix this problem:

```
JsonConfig cfg = new JsonConfig();
cfg.setExcludes(new String[]{"handler","hibernateLazyInitializer"});
JSONObject json = JSONObject.fromObject(obj,cfg);
```